# What to do with almost constant feature?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, lasso-regression

When a feature is almost constant, it gets eliminated by Lasso regularization. Does it mean that the information brought by the feature is superfluous and cannot be useful when applying time series or other ML models? Or are there strategies on how to deal with constant or almost constant features?

Answer (score 1):

Usually its a good idea to remove such features because if a feature is constant its not making any effect on the target variable and can be ignored. However if its 'almost' constant then it depends on the case you have. I suggest plot a correlation matrix and see how correlated this feature is with the target variable. It you can see that it has no correlation and its almost constant then probably its a good idea to ignore it (as done by Lasso) as its not significantly contributing to target variable.